# UseSelector in react-native return undefined but variable in redux get updated

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

i have trying to using UseSelector to get data in a redux, but it's alwas returned undefined, but when i try log console.log teh variable that i wanted to get in redux it's get updated, but when i try console log the useSelector it's returned undefined

code Redux :

```
export const EXCHAHNGETOSECOND = 'EXCHANGETOSECOND'

export const exchangetosecwork = (hour,minute,second) =>({
    type:EXCHAHNGETOSECOND,
    payloadhourwork : hour,
    payloadminutework : minute,
    payloadsecondwork : second
})

let initialState ={
    resultWorkinSecond : 0
}

export const mainReducer = (state=initialState, action) =>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case EXCHAHNGETOSECOND:
            const hourTosecond = action.payloadhourwork * 3600
            const minuteTosecond = action.payloadminutework * 60
            const res = hourTosecond+minuteTosecond+action.payloadsecondwork
            state.resultWorkinSecond = res
            console.log(state.resultWorkinSecond);
            return state.resultWorkinSecond
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default mainReducer
```

store redux :

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import mainReducer from "./redux";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'


const persistConfig={
    key:'root',
    storage:AsyncStorage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig,mainReducer)

export default() => {
    let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
    let persistor = persistStore(store)
    return{ store, persistor }
}
```

myConsole log test:

```
 const resWorkinSec = useSelector((state)=>state.resultWorkinSecond)
    
    <Pressable onPress={()=>{
                            dispatch(exchangetosecwork(hour,minute,second))
                            console.log(resWorkinSec)
                        }}>
```

[console log result [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wn0T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reducer has multiple bugs:

- it does an assignment, changing state. This is not allowed in legacy Redux reducers, but only in modern Redux using `createSlice`
- `return state.resultWorkinSecond` then even changes the full state structure.

Correct legacy Redux code would look like this:

```js
export const mainReducer = (state=initialState, action) =>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case EXCHAHNGETOSECOND:
            const hourTosecond = action.payloadhourwork * 3600
            const minuteTosecond = action.payloadminutework * 60
            const res = hourTosecond+minuteTosecond+action.payloadsecondwork
            return { ...state, resultWorkinSecond: res }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

All that said, this is an old style of Redux that we do not recommend any more since 2019. It is more complicated, and error-prone. And about 4 times the code modern Redux would be. Modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES, immtuable reducer logic (like you needed to do here), `createStore` and the likes.

I would highly recommend you drop what you are doing for a moment and go through the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).